# Flash buider eclipse plugin

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm working on an application in Flex using Flash Builder 4.7.
Now I want to uninstall and install the plugin for FlashBuilder eclipse.
I searched in the adobe site but I can't find the link to download the plugin, can anyone help me?
I use eclipse 4.3.1

Thank you!

Comment: If I remember well, it's the same installer. You just select 'plugin' or 'standalone' during the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder 4.7 only supports running on Eclipse 3.7 or 4.2 (not 4.3).  The installation is essentially for a stand-alone version now, but after you have installed, you can go into the Flash Builder installation folder (on Windows that will be under "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Flash Builder 4.7 (64-bit)" or "C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Flash Builder 4.7" for the 32-bit version).  There is a "utilities" folder with the following program you need to run:

Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Plug-in Utility.exe

Run that and select your eclipse folder and it should work as a plug-in in your Eclipse.  I tested it on Eclipse 4.4 and it would not run.  Note, upon running the utility, it will disable it working in stand-alone mode.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the flashbuillder installed on ur machine, then you will have the plugin installer also. Notes from adobe forum below.

- Navigate to the installed Flash Builder installation location and
  open the utilities folder.
- Run the executable Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 Plug-in Utility.exe.
- Select the language and click on OK.
- Select the Flash Builder installation location if prompted.
- Select    the Eclipse folder into which you want Flash Builder 4.6 to
  be    plugged into and click Next
  (Note: Your copy of Eclipse must be
  version 3.6/3.6.1/3.6.2/3.7, 32-bit and must contain a folder named
  “dropins”)
- Review the pre-Installation summary and click on Install

Ref: [Adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1030478)